# Email function using templates. Includes via ob_start and global vars

Tags: php, templates, global-variables, abstract-class, ob-start

I have a simple Email() class. It's used to send out emails from my website.

```
<?
Email::send($to, $subj, $msg, $options);
?>
```

I also have a bunch of email templates written in plain HTML pierced with a few PHP variables. E.g. `/inc/email/templates/account_created.php`:

```
<p>Dear <?=$name?>,</p>
<p>Thank you for creating an account at <?=$SITE_NAME?>. To login use the link below:</p>
<p><a href="https://<?=$SITE_URL?>/account" target="_blank"><?=$SITE_NAME?>/account</a></p>
```

In order to have the PHP vars rendered I had to `include` the template into my function. But since `include` does not return the contents but rather just sends it directly to the output, I had to wrap it with the buffer functions:

```
<?
abstract class Email {
    public static function send($to, $subj, $msg, $options = array()) {
        /* ... */
        ob_start();
        include '/inc/email/templates/account_created.php';
        $msg = ob_get_clean();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

After that I realized that the PHP vars are not rendered as they are being inside of the function scope, so I had to globalize the variables inside of the template:

```
<?
global $SITE_NAME, $SITE_URL, $name;
?>
<p>Dear <?=$name?>,</p>
...
```

So the question is whether there is a more elegant solution to this? Mainly I am concerned about my workarounds using `ob_start()` and `global`. For some reason that seems to me odd. Or this is pretty much the common practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a more elegant solution to your problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706855/send-email-with-a-template-using-php).
Notice the usage of the PHP [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to instantiate the template variables.
In other words, you should move the template parsing logic outside the e-mail sending function.
For example:

```
<?php

class SimpleTemplate {
    private $_tpl  = "";
    private $_vars = array();

    function __construct($tpl_name) {
         $this->_tpl = $tpl_name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->_vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function setVars($values) {
        $this->_vars = $values;
    }

    public function parse() {
        ob_start();
        extract($this->_vars);
        include $this->_tpl;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

abstract class Email {
    public static function send($to, $subj, $msg, $options = array()) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

$tpl = new SimpleTemplate('/inc/email/templates/account_created.php');
$tpl->name = 'Stack Overflow';
$tpl->SITE_NAME = 'site_name';
$tpl->SITE_URL = 'localhost';
Email::send("me@localhost", "Subject", $tpl->parse());

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to do this is to read the file content to the variable and then, using regexps, replace the placeholders. So for example you have new-users-template.phtml. You reading it content with `$content = file_get_content('new-users-templae.phtml');`. In those template you will have placeholders like `%%username%%`, `%%sitename%%`, `%%siteurl%%`. You need to process this content with `str_replace`, replacing the placeholders. Move this code to some `"prepareEmailTemplate"` function and put the result of this function to your `"send"` function.

Comment: Hmm.. That's something like smarty templates thing works, right? However the vars are still going need to be globalized inside of the function anyways.

Comment: Maybe, I didn't see the code of Smarty inside :) About the vars - you can provide them as the additional params to the send function. But the better choice would be to move the code for template parsing to another function and put the resulted content to send function

Comment: You could actually use your existing files in exactly this way, replacing the entire section of PHP, so something like `str_replace('<?=name;?>', 'Some name', $email_html);`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to globalize the variables needed not inside the template but inside the function `send`.

```
public static function send($to, $subj, $msg, $options = array()) {
    global $SITE_NAME, $SITE_URL, $name;

    /* ... */
    ob_start();
    include '/inc/email/templates/account_created.php';
    $msg = ob_get_clean();
    /* ... */
}
```

Another solution is to pass those extra variables as parameters. This maybe ugly as the number of parameters in the `set` function may grow a lot depending on how many of them you need in your template. To solve this issue, another way of implementing this solution is by passing those extra variables as a hash and create those variables on-the-fly (using the function `eval`). Here's an example:

```
public static function send($to, $extra_vars = array()) {
    foreach ($extra_vars as $key => $value) {
        eval("\$$key = '$value';");
    }

    /* ... */
    ob_start();
    include '/inc/email/templates/account_created.php';
    $msg = ob_get_clean();
    /* ... */
}
```

Then when you should call send like this:

```
$SITE_NAME = "www.somewebsite.com";
Email::send("recipient", array('SITE_NAME' => $SITE_NAME));
```

Comment: I in general don't like the idea of globalizing variables. Globalizing them in the function like you suggest seems to be a bit cleaner, but will require constant class modding when new variables are introduced in the templates. That's not fun. I sorta like your second idea of throwing them in the `send` function. I'll have to experiment with that a bit. I **definitely** wouldn't recommend using eval though. I'll better just update the templates to echo `$extra_vars['SITE_NAME']` instead. Thank you! P.S. Congrats on your reputation score!! :)

Comment: Yes, eval can be evil ;-) Having them in the template as an array can be nice too