# Sending email with PHP to include HTML file as well as PHP variables

Tags: php, html, email

I'm attempting to send webinar confirmation emails using PHP, however I want to have the email content be stored in a separate file on my server. I have figured out how to do this, however I have no idea how to pass variables to the separate HTML file.

Here is my PHP for email sending:

```
 $from    = "no-reply@thelaunchpadsoceity.com";
 $to      = $email;
 $subject = "You Are In!";

 //LINK TO SEPARATE HTML DOCUMENT THAT CONTAINS RESPONSIVE EMAIL FORMATTING
 $message = file_get_contents('./webinar_emails/registration_confirmed.html');
 $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

 mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

Is there a way I can pass variables such as the users first name, or the registration time of the webinar to the separate HTML file for display, and then email all those details to the user?

My separate email registration HTML file can be found [here](http://thelaunchpadsociety.com/webinar_emails/registration_confirmed.html).

I would like to put variables in the following sections of code:

```
      <span style="font-size: 26px; line-height: 31px;">YOUR WEBINAR INFORMATION IS AS FOLLOWS:</span></p>

<p style="margin: 0;font-size: 12px;line-height: 14px;text-align: left">
<strong>

         //ENTER VARIABLE FOR WEBINAR TITLE $webinarTitle AFTER "TITLE:"
           TITLE:</strong></p>

<p style="margin: 0;font-size: 12px;line-height: 14px;text-align: left">    
       //ENTER WEBINAR TIME VARIABLE AFTER "TIME:" $webinarTime
       <strong>TIME:</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass form variables into PHP?

Comment: the question is: what is inside that registration_confirmed.html file of yours. and yes, it can be done.

Comment: Yes, via $_POST then storing it as a SESSION.

Comment: The source code is rather long. I can try to post it, but it will be a lot of scrolling.

Comment: then narrow it down to the parts you want to use as the template. It's as simple as using `$vars`. Or post a minimal example.

Comment: Ok, I will do that now

Comment: I now know exactly what you should use for this; `ob_start()` to capture content. Consult both http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/4401949/1415724

Comment: I'm looking at your referenced links, however I don't really understand how to apply it to my application

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary solution by using string replace in PHP. This probably is not the best method to do so, however it has been the only method that has seemed to work so far.

You can reference the comments in the following post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767338/6703498