# Store PHP code in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have to send an email, the email can be formatted and stored in database. But the problem is I have to use some variable in the email to make it a dynamic email for each user.

```
INSERT INTO email (greeting) VALUES ( "Hello $name"); 

$coding = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email ") or die(mysql_error()); 
$email = mysql_fetch_array( $coding ); 

echo $email['greeting'];
```

it should echo Hello PERSONS_NAME; like Hello John, But it echo Hello $name, as it is..

Does not work, Any help ???

Comment: Your title says something your body says something else.

Comment: It seems like you want an email template. Typically you'd do something like replacing a placeholder value in your string with the "live" value. So `echo str_replace('$name', $name, $email['greeting'])`. Though you don't have to use $name as the placeholder; just any string that will be unique in your email. You're not actually storing "PHP code" in the database. Is that the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: Also: please don't use the elderly mysql extension. [It's deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email with a template using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706855/send-email-with-a-template-using-php)

Comment: @MattGibson It's not really a duplicate of that question because it focuses on storing the template in the database, not in code. (Arguments aside about the "right place" to put such things.)

Comment: @mosheKatz Thanks for clarifying, It is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably be better off using placeholders and then swap out the placeholder with dynamic text when sending the email:

```
INSERT INTO email (greeting) VALUES ( "Hello %%NAME%%");

$coding = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email ") or die(mysql_error()); 
$email = mysql_fetch_array( $coding ); 

$email['greeting'] = str_replace('%%NAME%%', $name, $email['greeting']);

echo $email['greeting'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps me a lot, But I'm not sure you people down voted me for the question ??