# Variables from database

Tags: php, sql

For automatise the email sending in PHP, i store the content of the emails in a database.

Is it possible to store the name of the variable in the database for using after run in the result of the query ? and how to do this?

I've try this: `$body = preg_replace('#\$[a-z0-9_]+#i', "$$0", $bodyFromDB);`

For example, i want to store this:

Dear $firstname $lastname, ...

Thanks for your help

PS: I am open to an other solution.

Final Edit: I've found my hapiness here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274461/7754097

Comment: Yes but it is a bad idea

Comment: Search for template systems.

Comment: Honestly I could be wrong, but I imagine the question you want to be asking is "I'm storing var names in the DB,how can I improve my approach"

Comment: @RiggsFolly, what is the better solution for this?

Comment: @James, Exactly

Comment: @Barmar, For example?

Comment: @DenisGermanier i usually use simple txt files (eg. Dear {1} {2}) and then pass the arguments in php.

Comment: @DenisGermanier I have no idea. Google is your friend.

Comment: The general concept is called "mail merge", google that.

Comment: @Barmar, Ok, i'll try this

Comment: I've found my hapiness here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17274461/7754097